# const ref and rvalue in D

Tags: d, ref, rvalue

Code

```
struct CustomReal
{
   private real value;

   this(real value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   CustomReal opBinary(string op)(CustomReal rhs) if (op == "+")
   {
      return CustomReal(value + rhs.value);
   }

   bool opEquals(ref const CustomReal x) const
   {
      return value == x.value; // just for fun
   }
}

// Returns rvalue 
CustomReal Create()
{
   return CustomReal(123.123456);
}

void main()
{
   CustomReal a = Create();
   assert(a == CustomReal(123.123456)); // OK. CustomReal is temporary but lvalue
   assert(a == Create());               // Compilation error (can't bind to rvalue)
   assert(a != a + a);                  // Compilation error (can't bind to rvalue)
}
```

Compilation error

```
prog.d(31): Error: function prog.CustomReal.opEquals (ref const const(CustomReal) x) const is not callable using argument types (CustomReal)
prog.d(31): Error: Create() is not an lvalue
```

http://ideone.com/O8wFc

Questions:

1. Why `const ref` can't bind to rvalue? Is it ok?
2. Do I need to return `ref CustomReal` or `const ref CustomReal` from `opBinary()` to fix this problem? Is it ok?
3. Is it correct to return a reference to local object created on stack?
   `ref CustomReal Create() { return CustomReal(0.0); }`

Comment: what happens when you use `in` instead of `ref const`

Comment: Compiler tells me that `opEquals()` should use `ref const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between `ref` and `const ref` is that `const ref` is `const` and `ref` is not. Both must take a variable. Neither can take a temporary. This is different from C++ where `const T&` will take any value of type `T` - including temporaries.

`opBinary` cannot return either `ref` or `const ref`, because there's no variable to return. It's creating a temporary. The same goes for `Create`. And creating a local variable with the value that you want to return doesn't help either, because you can't return a reference to a local variable. It would end up referring to a variable which didn't exist anymore.

What you need to do here is add another overload of `opEquals`:

```
bool opEquals(CustomReal x) const
{
    return value == x.value; // just for fun
}
```

With that, your code will compile.

I would point out though that the current situation with `opEquals` *does* need to be ironed out a bit. You'll notice that if you only have the overload for `opEquals` that I gave you and not the one that you currently have, the code fails to compile, and you get an error similar to this:

```
prog.d(15): Error: function prog.CustomReal.opEquals type signature should be const bool(ref const(CustomReal)) not const bool(CustomReal x)
```

The compiler is currently overly picky about the exact signature of `opEquals` for structs (a few other functions - such as `toString` - have similar issues). It's a known issue and will probably be resolved in the near future. However, for now, just declare both overloads of `opEquals`. If you compare a `CustomReal` with a variable, then the `const ref` version will be used, and if you compare a `CustomReal` with a temporary, then the other version will be used. But if you have both, you should be okay.

Now, why

```
assert(a == CustomReal(123.123456));
```

works, and

```
assert(a == Create());
```

doesn't, I'm not sure. I'd actually expect *both* of them to fail, given that `const ref` can't take a temporary, but for some reason, the compiler accepts it here - it probably has to do with how it treats `opEquals` special. Regardless, as I said, there are some issues with `opEquals` and structs which need to be ironed out, and hopefully that'll happen soon. But in the meantime, declaring both overloads of `opEquals` seems to do the trick.

**EDIT:** It appears that the reason that

```
assert(a == CustomReal(123.123456));
```

works, and

```
assert(a == Create());
```

doesn't is because of the fact (for reasons that I don't understand) a struct literal is considered an lvalue, whereas the return value of a function which is not `ref` is (unsurprisingly) an rvalue. There are a [couple](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=5889) of [bug reports](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3659) related to it, arguing that struct literals should be rvalues, but apparently they're lvalues by design (which baffles me). In any case, that's why a function which takes `const ref` works with a struct literal but not with the return value of a function.

Comment: I've overloaded opEquals(), but the compiler tells me that a function argument matches both opEquals(), so it can't be compiled. See http://ideone.com/4fyvG . It seems the problem is that `CustomReal(123.123456)` temporary object is not treated as rvalue. I do not understand why.

Comment: ideone's version of dmd is _way_ out of date. They're using 2.042. The latest  is 2.054. As long as its version of dmd is that old, you can't trust ideone as far as what will and won't compile. It's 12 releases behind.

Comment: I tested this on 2.053 on my home mac and it failed. I've just updated to 2.054 and it seems working. Thanks. Anyway, this bug is pretty fresh.

Comment: It may be. As I said, the issues with `opEquals` and structs, still needs some sorting out ( http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3659 ), so there's a good chance that the situation will change again in the future as that's sorted out. D, as a language, is fairly stable at this point, but some tweaks are made as necessary to sort out issues like this, and as bugs are fixed on the compiler, the behavior sometimes changes (usually for the better). So while things are stabilizing, they're still in a bit of flux, and using the most recent compiler can really matter for some things.

Comment: Since you're on a Mac, I would warn you though that the current release of dmd (and every release ever IIUC) doesn't work properly on the new Mac OS X release, Lion ( http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/OS_X_10.7_Lion_breaks_DMD-compiled_executables_due_to_ASLR_141150.html and http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Lion-compatibilty_emergency_release_or_put_warning_on_download_page_141729.html ). It should be fixed in the next release, but you could have memory issues due to the new ASLR in Lion.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will delay upgrading to Lion, especially it is not a primary platform for me (unhappily :)

Answer (score 3):

`#1`: Yep, const ref can't bind to rvalues. Andrei thinks it was a bad idea to allow that in C++ IIRC.
http://digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/const_ref_rvalues_103509.html#N103514

The weird thing is struct literals count as lvalues in D2, so this works:

```
struct A {}
void foo(ref A a) {}
void main()
{
    foo(A());
}
```

while calling the following doesn't:

```
static A bar()
{
    return A();
}

foo(bar());
```

Comment: Do you remember what were his arguments ? Or maybe you have a link ?

Comment: http://digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/const_ref_rvalues_103509.html#N103514

Comment: use mark-down for links, like `[visible text](url)`. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). (and thanks for the link)

Answer (score 2):

For #2 (and by extension #3): No, that would be invalid as it would have to be a reference to an object that had just gong out of scope.